# Assigning values to words based on position of letters in alphabet

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have an array of names. Each letter gets a value of 1 to 26 for the alphabet. Then the letter is multiplied by its place in the list. I came up with the following algorithm:

```
score = 0
names.each_with_index do |name, index|
    temp = 0
    letters = name.to_s.scan(/(.)/)
    letters.each do |letter|
        temp += 1 if letter.to_s.match(/A/)
        temp += 2 if letter.to_s.match(/B/)
        temp += 3 if letter.to_s.match(/C/)
        temp += 4 if letter.to_s.match(/D/)
        temp += 5 if letter.to_s.match(/E/)
        temp += 6 if letter.to_s.match(/F/)
        temp += 7 if letter.to_s.match(/G/)
        temp += 8 if letter.to_s.match(/H/)
        temp += 9 if letter.to_s.match(/I/)
        temp += 10 if letter.to_s.match(/J/)
        temp += 11 if letter.to_s.match(/K/)
        temp += 12 if letter.to_s.match(/L/)
        temp += 13 if letter.to_s.match(/M/)
        temp += 14 if letter.to_s.match(/N/)
        temp += 15 if letter.to_s.match(/O/)
        temp += 16 if letter.to_s.match(/P/)
        temp += 17 if letter.to_s.match(/Q/)
        temp += 18 if letter.to_s.match(/R/)
        temp += 19 if letter.to_s.match(/S/)
        temp += 20 if letter.to_s.match(/T/)
        temp += 21 if letter.to_s.match(/U/)
        temp += 22 if letter.to_s.match(/V/)
        temp += 23 if letter.to_s.match(/W/)
        temp += 24 if letter.to_s.match(/X/)
        temp += 25 if letter.to_s.match(/Y/)
        temp += 26 if letter.to_s.match(/Z/)
    end
    score += (index+1) * temp
end

puts score
```

This is quite slow code. I hope someone can explain me a better and faster way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Erwin, someone just upvoted my answer, which prompted me to make some changes to it (being older and wiser since I wrote last year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

**Assumptions**

- the only characters are upper- and lower-case letters and whitespace.
- after converting all characters of each element of the array to lower case, you want the letter offsets from `a` for each word to be summed and then multiplied by the (base 1) position of the word in the array.

**Code**

```
def totals_by_name(names)
  names.each.with_index(1).with_object({}) { |(name,i),tots|
    tots[name] = i*(name.downcase.each_char.reduce(0) { |tot,c|
      tot + c.ord - 'a'.ord + 1 }) }
end

def total(names)
  totals_by_name(names).values.reduce(:+)
end
```

**Example**

```
names = %w{ Joanne Jackie Joe Jethro Jack Jill }
  #=> ["Joanne", "Jackie", "Joe", "Jethro", "Jack", "Jill"] 

total(names)
  #=> 914
```

**Explanation**

For the method `totals_by_name` and the array `names` above:

```
e0 = names.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Joanne", "Jackie", "Joe", "Jethro", "Jack", "Jill"]:each>
```

We can see the values this enumerator will pass on by converting it to an array:

```
e0.to_a
  #=> ["Joanne", "Jackie", "Joe", "Jethro", "Jack", "Jill"]
```

Continuing,

```
e1 = e0.with_index(1)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["Joanne", "Jackie", "Joe", "Jethro",
  #     "Jack", "Jill"]:each>:with_index(1)> 
e1.to_a
  #=> [["Joanne", 1], ["Jackie", 2], ["Joe", 3], ["Jethro", 4], ["Jack", 5], ["Jill", 6]]
e2 = e1.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["Joanne", "Jackie", "Joe",
  #     "Jethro", "Jack", "Jill"]:each>:with_index(1)>:with_object({})> 
e2.to_a
  #=> [[["Joanne", 1], {}], [["Jackie", 2], {}], [["Joe", 3],  {}],
  #    [["Jethro", 4], {}], [["Jack", 5],   {}], [["Jill", 6], {}]]
```

We can think of `e2` and `e3` as *compound* enumerators.

Enumerator#each passes elements of `e2` to the block and assigns values to the block variables. We can use Enumerator#next to see what happens:

```
(name,i),tots = e2.next
     #=> [["Joanne", 1], {}] 
name #=> "Joanne" 
i    #=> 1 
tots #=> {}
```

The block calculation is:

```
e3 = name.downcase.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "joanne":each_char> 
e3.to_a # have a look
  #=> ["j", "o", "a", "n", "n", "e"] 

e3.reduce(0) { |tot,c| tot + c.ord - 'a'.ord + 1 }
  #=> 59
```

For

```
c = "j"
```

this block calculation is:

```
tot + c.ord - 'a'.ord + 1
  #=> 0 + 106 - 97 + 1
  #=> 10
```

Therefore:

```
tots[name] = i*(name.downcase.each_char.reduce(0) { |tot,c|
  tot + c.ord - 'a'.ord + 1 })    
  #=> tots["Joanna"] = 1*(59)
tots
  #=> {"Joanne"=>59}
```

Values for other names are calculated similarly. The method `tots` is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I would most likely go with:

```
class String
  def points
    each_char.map.with_index do |char, index|
      (char.downcase.ord - 96) * (index + 1)
    end.inject(0, :+)  
  end
end

'Hello'.points  #=> 177
```

Comment: BroiSatse, I'm curious why you chose to create an array and then apply `inject`, rather than just `inject` directly: `each_char.with_index.inject(0) {|tot,(c,i)| tot+(c.downcase.ord-96)*(i+1)}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree, that this would be faster as it would only iterates once, however this way is much more readable and since this is usually to be used on single words, the gain would be pretty small. Actually, avoiding double iteration can be achieved using lazy iterator.

Comment: It is multiplied by the index in the list. Not the index of the character. But this is indeed readable. thanks!

Comment: I used your extension method of String and made this: https://github.com/erooijak/projecteuler/blob/master/22.rb